# why is the first line shifted by printing a star rectangle?

Tags: c++

it looks like this:[

```
  +++++
 +   +
 +   +
 +++++
```

] I'm using by the way Clion and I don't know if this happens 'cause of some configuration!!

I m trying to print out a star rectangle but the first line is shifted to the right side, could you please help me and say why is it looks like this?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    int m,n;
    std:: cout<< "Enter first number: ";
    std:: cin>> m;
    std:: cout<< "Enter second number: ";
    std:: cin>> n;

    for(int i = 0; i <m; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (j==0 || i==0 || (i==m-1) || (j==n-1)){
                cout<<"+";
            } else{
                cout<<" ";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Can you show us how exactly it's shifted?

Comment: looks fine to me: https://godbolt.org/z/afP4ErGz4
Something else is offsetting your text before you write it.  Possibly the I/O to get m and n, but maybe when you see the problem you have other code printing something first that you're not considering.

Comment: Do a `cout << endl;` before the first `for`. You see that both `cin>>` leave an extra space.